# Streamlit: pass the widget input to its own callback

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I'd like to capture a text in a [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.text_input) `text_area` widget (for instance, but any widget that produces input should work the same), and pass the captured text to the callback. How could I do that ? (if it's possible).

So far I've tried:

```py
import streamlit as st

def callback(string):
    print(string) # do something using a string here
```

and then either

```py
text_input = st.text_area("Enter a text", key="input_text", 
                          on_change=callback,
                          args=(text_input,))

# text_input does not exist
```

or

```py
text_input = st.text_area("Enter a text", key="input_text", 
                          on_change=callback,
                          args=(st.session_state.input_text,))

# session_state.input_text is not initialized
```

both result in errors.

My basic usage is e.g.:

- add a user comment on a log-like file in the back
- append a string to a list in the back

I found a workaround

```py
input_text= st.text_area("Enter a text", key="input_text")

if input_text!= st.session_state.input_text:
     callback(input_text)
     st.session_state.input_text = input_text
st.button("Callback", on_click=callback(input_text))
```

following a [tutorial on towardsdatascience](https://towardsdatascience.com/advanced-streamlit-session-state-and-callbacks-for-data-labelling-tool-1e4d9ad32a3f) but I'mn not entirely satisfied with it, as it has two widgets that may compete with each other while I need only one.

Answer (score 14):

Do like this. Notice the press cntrl+enter to apply.

###### Code

```
def proc():
    st.write(st.session_state.text_key)

st.text_area('enter text', on_change=proc, key='text_key')
```

###### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
st.button("Callback", on_click=callback(input_text))
```

didn't work for me but the following did

```
def waschanged(key):
    st.info(st.session_state[key])

setBrightness = st.slider("Brightness", -10, 10, 0, step=1, key="Brightness", on_change=waschanged, args=("Brightness",))
```

This prints the latest changed variable